# Can't find suitable onCreate() equivalent for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I already read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

I'm moving some activity code to a brand new fragment, but have found a problem with the code previously in onCreate().

- Purpose of using fragments: tabs.
- Code called on each tab switch:

  `FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();`

  `FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();`

  `ft.replace(R.id.tabContent, fragment1);`

  `ft.commit();`

Where fragment1, fragment2, etc. Are instance variables of the activity, instantiated in `onCreate`:

```
fragment1 = new Fragment1();
//etc.
```

- How I want them to work: Like the activity (!), means: After created - where I call my webservice, and the list is initialized the first time, there is *no more initialization*, so when I switch tabs the list just remains how I left it (scroll, etc.), when I come back there's no view initialization or webservice call, it just appears again. Like in the activity, if I launch another activity, and come back - `onCreate()` will not be called, only `onResume()`. And since I'm initializing only in `onCreate()`, it's fine.

I'm calling in onCreate() a webservice to get data to populate a list. According to the lifecycle of a fragment, there are a few candidates to put this code, but none works entirely:

1. onCreate(): This is called before onCreateView(). So the view hierarchy isn't initialized yet and it would be unsafe to call the webservice.
2. onCreateView(): This is called always when I switch tab / run the shown code snippet.
3. onActivityCreated(): I thought this would be called *only* after the activity was created, but it's called *always* after Fragment.onCreateView()

As a side question, do you recommend calling webservices in the fragments? Haven't find anything about this in the web, but wouldn't know why it's incorrect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nothing is incorrect, but since you started with this code in you activity, why don't you leave the calls in your activity and in your fragments, check for the data and if its not there, ask the activity to get them

Comment: Well, on one side, because I thought that the webservice call is only business of the fragment, so why not put it there... Don't see a good reason to let it in the activity (besides "it doesn't work"). On the other side not quite sure yet at which point it would be safe to initialize and populate the fragment - but haven't thought about this approach yet.

Comment: And anyways your suggestion doesn't solve that `onCreateView()` runs each time that I switch tabs. This has a few undesired effects like resetting the scroll position of the list. Isn't there a way to just get the same functionality as with onCreate() and onResume()...

Comment: It is definitely more reasonable to have your data in a fragment if it is dependant, but you might as well centralize your data. `onCreateView()` being called each time depends on your code and not on where to put the data. Anyway, it can easily be solved depending on your code. Good luck

Comment: Weeell. thanks for your intentions, but these advices are a bit to vague. Currently I have my (memory)data in activities. What is the difference to have it in framents, being framents reusable modules- but principially the same as activities(view+behaviour)?. And the `onCreateView()` sentence was not understandable.

Comment: This is becoming more complicated than expected and I'll probably just use 2 views in my activity and toggle visible/gone. Don't have a particular reason to user fragments yet, besides I thought it would lead to a cleaner structure... but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I believe fragments are good once you get used to them. It is easier for example to use a specific fragment anywhere when you need it. You can handle data inside them: it is normal. You can start your asynctask if data is not available in `onCreateView` and, otherwise, set the data in the view before returning. I have used this approach and it is always working for me.

Comment: @Ixx did you solve this? or what did you ended up doing? im desperately looking for a solution!

Comment: I forgot even why I was doing that... but with my (improved) knowledge, I would say, one option could be to use a view pager and setup to keep the fragments in memory... or add to the backstack and pop, but this doesn't work for tabs. Or use onSaveInstanceState of the fragment... it's even possible to save the complete fragment instance as far I remember (but not recommended). Other than that, maybe implement a local database cache, such that the re-creation of the fragment doesn't create mayor lag.

Answer (score 1):

For me, `onActivityCreated` seems more or less the matching stage (at this time it is already possible to call `findViewById` on the parent activity and setup components / assign fields in the fragment instance / set (not add) listeners. My `onActivityCreated` is such that running it more than once does not make any harm and the passed `Bundle` parameter is taken into consideration.

Speaking about web services, you probably can call from anywhere but you cannot call from the GUI thread (and Android will not allow) - so create your own therad. You probably do not need to support fully switching between fragments and activities while some call to the web service is pending; if you do need, use the `savedInstanceState` bundle to save and resume the state when requested.

Comment: I am calling the werbservices from threads already. If the user switches between tabs or activities, it's fine to lose the data. The webservice will be called again next time. But what I need, and what the question is about, is that I want that the fragment just "freezes" like activity when navigate somewhere else and go back - because I *don't* want views to be initialized again, so scrolling position of the list will not be reset, etc.

Comment: Simply implement onSaveInstanceState that the system will call when relevant, and take the passed Bundle into consideration inside onActivityCreated (maybe null, if not null, restore the state). That way you will be able to save and restore the state.

Comment: Yes, I also knew about this already. I was just looking for an equivalent of the activity code - where I don't have to save/restore any state (in my case it's ok to lose the data if the activity is destroyed).

Comment: So you know very much already ... lets wait for more answers.

Comment: Well, being a community site doesn't necessarily exclude the existence of ironic comments and some other not ideal behaviors. But I'm informed that your comment wasn't ironic.

Comment: The idea was to say lets now wait for some other user to answer that question.

Comment: anyways... im facing this exact same problem as @Ixx and cant seem to find an answer!! What did you end up doing man?

Answer (score 1):

Use Loaders:

Create a subclass of an AsyncLoader and start/initialize these loader in your Fragment's onActivityCreated implementation:

```
public abstract class MyLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<String> {
public MyLoader(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

private String result;
protected String error;

@Override
public final String loadInBackground() {
    try {
        error = null;
        // Load your data from the server using HTTP and store result as string in 'result'.
        ...
        result = ...
        ...
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.e("ResourceLoader", "Loading resource failed.", e);
        error = e.getMessage();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(error)) {
        deliverResult(result);
    }

    if (takeContentChanged()) {
        forceLoad();
    }
}

@Override
public void deliverResult(String data) {
    if (isReset()) {
        return;
    }

    result = data;

    if (isStarted()) {
        try {
            super.deliverResult(data);
        }
        catch(Exception e) { 
            Log.e("ResourceLoader", "Caught exception while delivering result.", e);
        }
    }
}

public String getError() {
    return error;
}
}
```

In your Fragment, you can initialize this loader:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<String> {
....
....
String message;
TextView textView;

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRetainInstance(true);
        ....
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = ....
    ...
    textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.....);
    textView.setMessage(message); // in case this Fragment1 survived an orientation change.
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, getArguments(), this); // Start loading data after activity has been created.
}

@Override
public Loader<String> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new MyLoader(getActivity()); // Load data using MyLoader
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<String> loader, String result) {
    // Here you have the result in 'result'.
    message = result;
    if (textView != null) {
        // Update UI according to result.
        textView.setText(message);
        ....
    }
    ...
}
....
}
```

In the onLoadFinished, you store the result in 'message'. If a simple String is not sufficient as a result, you can change MyLoader and LoaderCallbacks to return and handle more complex data-structures (e.g. List<String>, for example).

Comment: Thanks, this would be a very good answer if I asked what you are answering... but I'm not... the question is not how to load data asynchronously. I also know that I can call the webservice / loader / whatever I use to fetch the data in onActivityCreated. But as described in the question, this doesn't behave like I would like it to.

Comment: The ViewPager (working together with its PagerAdapter) destroys and (re)creates the Fragments it hosts (i.e. it manager their lifecycles) and there is very little you can do to change this.

However, you can save the returned data in the Fragment's savedInstanceState (contents and list-position) and restore it when the Fragment is re-created.

Or you can cache the returned HTTP response from the server and just save list-position in the Fragment's savedInstanceState.

Comment: I have similar code in my app. In my app, I don't save the ListView contents nor the list/scroll position in the savedInstanceState. I just make sure that the setRetainInstance(true) is called and it all just works: Contents are restored as the user left it.

Note that I do cache the HTTP results.

Comment: I'm not using a ViewPager. Just fragments directly. But yes, it seems that I have to adapt my current logic. I just thought I could copy paste my current things in the lifecycle of the fragment, but that, of course, was naive...